# Kendo Datasource Transport custom function not getting called

Tags: kendo-ui

Im experiencing a rather annoying bug (?) in Kendo UI Datasource.

My Update method on my transport is not getting called when I pass a custom function, but it does work if I just give it the URL.

This works:

```
...
transport: {
   update: { url: "/My/Action" }
}
...
```

This does not

```
...
transport: {
   update: function(options) {
      var params = JSON.stringify({
            pageId: pageId,
            pageItem: options.data
      });
      alert("Update");
      $.ajax({
            url: "/My/Action",
            data:params,
            success:function(result) {
                options.success($.isArray(result) ? result : [result]);
            }
      });
   }
}
...
```

The function is not getting invoked, but an ajax request is made to the current page URL, and the model data is being posted, which is rather odd. Sounds like a bug to me.

The only reason I have a need for this, is because Kendo can't figure out that my update action returns only a single element, and not an array - so, since I dont want to bend my API just to satisfy Kendo, I though I'd do it the other way around.

Have anyone experienced this, and can point me in the right direction?

I also tried using the schema.parse, but that didn't get invoked when the Update method was being called.

I use `myDs.sync()` to sync my datasource.

Comment: I have same problem, not sure if it is fixed...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Works as expected with the demo from the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.update):

```js
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: function(options) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(result) {
            options.success(result);
          }
        });

      },
      update: function(options) {
        alert(1);
        // make JSONP request to http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products/update

        $.ajax( {
          url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products/update",
          dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
          // send the updated data items as the "models" service parameter encoded in JSON
          data: {
            models: kendo.stringify(options.data.models)
          },
          success: function(result) {
            // notify the data source that the request succeeded

            options.success(result);
          },
          error: function(result) {
            // notify the data source that the request failed
            options.error(result);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    batch: true,
    schema: {
      model: { id: "ProductID" }
    }
  });

  dataSource.fetch(function() {
    var product = dataSource.at(0);
    product.set("UnitPrice", product.UnitPrice + 1);        
    dataSource.sync();
  });
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/omomes/1/edit

Comment: Try this: http://jsbin.com/oguxac/1/ - only difference is I am not using a custom function for Read. Maybe thats the problem. If you look at the console, an error is thrown in kendo.

Comment: That's the problem. You need to use a custom function for read() as well.

Comment: But why is that necessary? If thats the case, is there an easier way to do what I need to do in the update method, without having to provide my own function just to make the result into an array?

Comment: You can check the source code to see why it is necessary - kendo.data.js. You can also check the DataSource API reference - schema.parse is what you need.

Comment: I tried schema.parse (as stated in my question), and it was only called when reading, not updating.

Comment: But it's not - the response contains a JSON object rather than an array.

Comment: I have no idea why, but I tried using schema.parse again, and this time it worked. If you add the schema parse to your answer, I will mark it as accepted.